# DbFunctions DiffDays Gives wrong answer

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, dbfunctions

I want to get a list from DataBase, where MyDate is today or tomarrow.
I wrote the following code.

```
_Log("Now: " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

var v = db_TS.TS_Test.Where(x => DbFunctions.DiffDays(x.MyDate,DateTime.Now) < 2);
foreach (var item in v.ToList())
{
     _Log("MyDate: " + item.MyDate.ToString());
}
```

The following is logged:

Now: 11/08/2016 10:50:00
MyDate: 27/09/2017 09:35:00

Please help me to find what went wrong in the code?
Thank you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should be doing `DbFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now,x.MyDate)` since it's supposed to work like subtracting the first parameter from the second one, so in your case, the DiffDays is returning a negative number.

Summarizing it if you have `DbFunctions.DiffDays(date1,date2)`

and `date1 > date2` the result will be `< 0`

and `date1 < date2` the result will be `> 0`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach is to check year, month, and day with the current date. Month and year should be the same. Day has to be the same for today and one day less for tomorrow:

```
var v = db_TS.TS_Test.Where(x => x.MyDate.Year == DateTime.Now.Year &&
                                 x.MyDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && 
                                 x.MyDate.Day >= DateTime.Now.Day - 1);
```

**Edit**

As pointed out this simplistic scenario won't work for edge cases.

Better option is to subtract a date from today and check what's the result in days. If it's tomorrow then the difference is 1 day or 0 if it's today.

```
var v = db_TS.TS_Test.Where(x => DateTime.Now.Subtract(x.MyDate).Days <= 1);
```

Comment: I think this will fail at the year boundary.

Comment: @AdamV You are absolutely right. I added more robust solution. Left the old one in case someone would like to use the idea and improve on that.

Answer (score 0):

please check here from more info of [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function.

- Syntax

  -- DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )

  -- Example usage

  ```
    SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1) AS DayDiff
    SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1) AS MinuteDiff
    SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1) AS SecondDiff
    SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1) AS WeekDiff
    SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, GETDATE(), GETDATE() + 1) AS HourDiff
  ```

You can  [play with here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/523301)

Comment: This person was asking about DbFunctions.DiffDays in EF, not directly in SQL  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.diffdays?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_Objects_EntityFunctions_DiffDays_System_Nullable_System_DateTime__System_Nullable_System_DateTime__)